# broadcast receiver not receiving Intent through Service

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement a Broadcast Receiver who should receive Intent from a Service which is running in the background, however it is not working.

In my main Activity I just bind the service and start it via `onClick` on a Button.

In my `SpeechRecognizer` Service class I create a new `BroadcastReceiver` (see code below).

```
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");             

    if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)){                         //check if a SpeechRecognizer is available
        this.sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
        this.sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());  

        commandsReceiver = new CommandsReceiver();
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        testfilter = new IntentFilter();
        registerReceiver(commandsReceiver,testfilter);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please install a SpeechRecognizer on your system.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //alert if speech-recognizer is not installed on the device
        Log.d(TAG, "no SpeechRecognizer available");
        this.onDestroy();
    }   
}
```

In my `onResult` I do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(CommandsReceiver.TEST);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In my `CommandsReceiver` I just got a simple `String` and a Log message:

```
public class CommandsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TEST = "de.speech.TEST_INTENT";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BroadCastReceiver", "Intent received"+intent);
    }
}
```

However I'm not getting the `Log.d()` message.

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are creating an IntentFilter without any Action as

```
testfilter = new IntentFilter();
```

instead of,

```
testfilter = new IntentFilter(CommandsReceiver.TEST);
```

so, register your BroadCast using,

```
testfilter = new IntentFilter(CommandsReceiver.TEST);
registerReceiver(commandsReceiver,testfilter);
```

Comment: As you are a new user and you haven't checked any answer. Better start check marking answers that you are satisfied with. So, that future user's can get to know that this answer is already answered.